# With $\lambda^*$ as the Lebesgue outer measure, $\epsilon\in(0,1),\ \lambda^*(E)>0$, find interval $I$ s.t. $\lambda^*(E\cap I)>\epsilon\lambda^*(I)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

We're to show that some interval $I$ satisfies the condition in the title. I.e., there exists an interval $I$ such that $\lambda^*(E\cap I)>\epsilon\lambda^*(I)$.

I know that because any interval $I$ is Lebesgue-measurable, we have that 
$$
\lambda^*(E) = \lambda^*(E\cap I) + \lambda^*\left(E\cap I^C\right)
$$
and therefore
$$
\lambda^*(E\cap I) = \lambda^*(E) - \lambda^*(E\cap I^C)$$
I think it should be possible for me to somehow specify an $I$ -- say, by finding a value $m$ such that $I=\left(-\frac m2,\frac m2\right)$ -- such that 
$$
\lambda^*(E) - \lambda^*(E\cap I^C) > \epsilon \lambda^*(I) = \epsilon m
$$
but I can't figure out a way to choose such an $m$.

Am I on the right track? If so, how to proceed? If not, what should I be doing instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the statement is false, then there exists $\epsilon\in (0,1)$ such that $$\lambda^*(E\cap I)\leq \epsilon \lambda^*(I)$$
for any inverval $I$.

Then there exists a sequence of open intervals $\{I_n\}$ such that $$E\subset \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}I_n=U$$ and $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\lambda^*(I_n)< \lambda^*(E)+\frac{1-\epsilon}{\epsilon}\lambda^*(E)=\frac{1}{\epsilon}\lambda^*(E)$$

Then observe that 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\lambda^*(I_n)<\frac{1}{\epsilon}\lambda^*(E)\leq \frac{1}{\epsilon}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\lambda^*(E\cap I_n)\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \lambda^*(I_n)  .$$

Then we have $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \lambda^*(I_n)<\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \lambda^*(I_n)$$ and it is a contradiction. Therefore, the statement is true.