# Let $\lambda(A)$ be the Lebesgue measure of $A$. There exists an interval $I$ such that $\lambda(E \cap I) / \lambda(I) < 1-\epsilon$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

(Not mentioned in title but $\epsilon$ is a number greater than $0$ and $E$ a Lebesgue measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.) I know a question equivalent to this one has been asked ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1782402/with-lambda-as-the-lebesgue-outer-measure-epsilon-in0-1-lambdae)). But it was not answered. Also my thinking is a bit different. So I would love to get some help on this problem.
So far I've got:

$$\frac{\lambda(E \cap I)}{\lambda(I)} > 1- \epsilon \iff \frac{\lambda(I)-\lambda(E\cap I)}{\lambda(I)} < \epsilon$$

And also, a theorem states that, for all $\epsilon$ there exists a closed set $F\subset E$ such that $\lambda(E\setminus F) < \epsilon$ so it would sufice to prove  that there exists an interval $I$ such that
$$\frac{\lambda(I)-\lambda(E\cap I)}{\lambda(I)}<\lambda(E\setminus F).$$
I'm not sure if this helps me much but any help is appreciated. What would you do?

Comment: WHat is $E{}{}$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown A Lebesgue measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: I'm not convinced that's true.

Comment: Your "$\Leftrightarrow$" should have the inequality reversed, id est $\dfrac{\lambda(I)-\lambda(E\cap I)}{\lambda (I)}>\epsilon$.

Comment: I mean $\mathbb{R}^n \ \mathbb{Q}$ (just take out the rationals) is a Lebesgue measurable (proper) subset of \mathbb{R}^n, and yet no such interval exists. (If you limit your sets to be of finite outer measure (which should be the condition for your theorem), then the problem becomes kind of trivial) I could be wrong though.

Comment: This question doesn't make sense. If $E = \mathbb{R}$ then the value is one for all non trivial intervals $I$. If $n>1$ then the measure of an interval is zero so the ratio makes no sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement is false. For example, $\mathbb{R}$ is Lebesgue measurable but $\frac{\lambda(I\cap \mathbb{R})}{\lambda(I)}=1\not< 1-\epsilon.$

(restriction to proper subset of $\mathbb{R}$ behave as $\mathbb{R}$ since $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$.)

I can prove it when $\overline{E}\neq \mathbb{R}.$

If $\epsilon \geq 1$, it does not make any sense. Thus, let's assume that $0<\epsilon<1$.

But it is trivial. Let $A=\overline{E}$ be the closure of $E$, then $A$ is Lebesgue measurable. Then $A^c$ is open. Note that $A^c$ is a countable disjoint union of open intervals. Just choose one of them,(Let's say $I$). Then clearly, $\lambda(E\cap I)=0$ and $\lambda(I)>0$ so clearly $$\frac{\lambda(E\cap I)}{\lambda(I)}=0<1-\epsilon . $$

If you want to prove that

> when $E$ is positive Lebesgue measurable set then for any $\epsilon\in (0,1)$, there exists an interval $I$ such that $$\frac{\lambda(E\cap I)}{\lambda(I)}>1-\epsilon,$$

it is a little bit difficult. **But the proof is as follow.**

Let's assume that the statement is false. Then there exists such $\epsilon $ such that for any interval $I$$$\lambda(E\cap I)\leq (1-\epsilon)\lambda(I).$$

Note that $$\lambda(E)=\inf\left\{\lambda(U): E\subset U \text{ and } U \text{ is open.}   \right\}.$$

Thus, there exists open set $U$ such that $E\subset U$ and 
$$ \lambda(U)<\lambda(E)+\frac{\epsilon}{1-\epsilon}\lambda(E) = \left(\frac{1}{1-\epsilon} \right)\lambda(E)$$

Note that $U$ is countable disjoint union of open intervals $\{I_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}.$

Now observe that

$$\lambda(U)<\frac{1}{1-\epsilon} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \lambda(E\cap I_n)\leq \frac{1}{1-\epsilon} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-\epsilon)\lambda(I_n)=\lambda(U)  $$

And note that $\lambda(U)<\lambda(U)$ does not make sense. Thus, it is a contradiction. Therefore, the statement is true.

Comment: Nope. Yes, $A^c$ is open, but it could be empty..

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich You are right! let me fix it ! Thanks for comment

Comment: I am terribly sorry, when writing the question I got the inequalities mixed up. Thanks for your help and taking into account both cases!

Comment: Also, I found a small typo - after the existence of $U$, the second term in the inequality should read $\frac{\epsilon}{1-\epsilon}\lambda(E)$ (you forgot $\lambda(E)$)

Comment: @D.Brito Thanks I corrected!