# Prove that $\lim_{m(I)\rightarrow 0}\frac{m(E\cap I)}{m(I)}=c$ for some $c$ and moving interval $I$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, borel-sets

Let $E$ be a set such that $m(E)>0$, $E \subset (0,1)$. Prove that there exists $c>0$ such that for some moving interval $I$, $$\lim_{m(I)\rightarrow 0}\frac{m(E\cap I)}{m(I)}=c$$

Proof: $m(E)=1$

My attempt:

I have proof E is dense in(0,1),proof by contradiction  if E nowhere dense in (0,1), there exist $(a,b)$ such that $(a,b)\subset (0,1)-E$, then $m((a,b)\cap E)=0$,we get a conflict

I think Maybe need the theorem using in construct unmeasurable set:
If m(E)>0, then for any $a \in (0,1)$,there exist an interval J,such that $m(E\cap J)>am(J)$

Comment: $E$ being dense does not tell you that $m(E)=1$.

Comment: @nicomezi you are right

Comment: Do not add back irrelevant tags. Thank you.

Comment: @AsafKaragila sorry

Comment: I think getting contradiction from assuming that $E$ is nowhere dense does not tell you $E$ is dense since being not dense does not mean it is nowhere dense

Comment: @LevBan yes but I don’t know how to solve the question can you help me..I think maybe use contradiction?

Comment: I am not sure but it would be helpful?   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2896620/let-lambdaa-be-the-lebesgue-measure-of-a-there-exists-an-interval-i-su/2896665#2896665

Comment: @LevBan thanks I am reading it

Comment: I still can’t work through it.. can you help me..

Comment: @LevBan I still can’t work through it can you help me

Comment: @jackson I am not sure if I have an idea, but I will try.  I will write the answer as soon as I can come up with the solution :)

Comment: @LevBan wow thanks a lot

Comment: @jackson there is a proof for your problem.  There are already several different proof for this problem :)  hope it helps. 


https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/596676/lebesgue-density-theorem-in-the-line

Comment: Thanks I am reading it

Comment: @jackson great!